# Writing indicators with Python, GIR and GTK3

Tags: indicator, python, application-development

I'm writing an application that needs to use an indicator. I've done this in the past using PyGTK and GTK2, using as reference this document: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators#Python_version

However, that only works with PyGTK and GTK2. Things have changed since then, and I need to find some good documentation, a tutorial or a good example to learn how it works.

Also, one thing that the previously mentioned document doesn't describe at all, is how to add sub-menus to an indicator. I hope someone can shed some light on this, as well as how to integrate with category indicators if that's done using the same tool.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/sagarchalise/My-Ubuntu-Unity-Indicators/blob/gpaste-indicator/gpaste-indicator/gpaste-indicator) is my trial code for gtk3 and appindicator which creates a indicator for [GPaste](https://github.com/Keruspe/GPaste).

Basically,

```
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as AppIndicator
```

in order to use appindicator for gtk3 applications which is provided by package `gir1.2-appindicator3`.

Here is the [AppIndicator3](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.04/python/AppIndicator3-0.1.html) documentation.

[pygtk](http://pygtk.org) will be deprecated for Gtk3 and you have to go through [GObject-Introspection](http://live.gnome.org/GObjectIntrospection) route for developing Gtk3 applications in python. You can refer to [PyGObject documentation](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Instead of

```
import pygtk, gtk, gdk, gobject, pango
```

etc you should do

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, Pango, GObject
```

For studying a working code, you could view [Kazam](http://launchpad.net/kazam) which has moved to gtk3 from gtk2 and uses [appindicator3](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~kazam-team/kazam/unstable/view/head:/kazam/frontend/indicator.py).

There is a package `gir1.2-appindicator` as well which seems to be same as using `python-appindicator` as they both provide usage for gtk2 appplication which is:

```
from gi.repository import AppIndicator
```

OR

```
import appindicator
```

Some information in [this blog post](http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2011/08/06/ubuntu-app-indicators-when-using-pygobject/) as well.

Comment: I went with AppIndicator3. But does this mean that AppIndicator 1 is a direct port of python-appindicator whereas AI3 is a new version that isn't backported?

Comment: It seems that way. I loaded appindicator 0.1 from python shell and then tried loading appindicator3 which gave me this error `RepositoryError: Requiring namespace 'Gtk' version '3.0', but '2.0' is already loaded`. So it seems appindicator 0.1 works with gtk2 i.e. pygtk and appindicator3  and above if any works with gtk3

Comment: Ah, I get it. It's not version 3 of AI. It's AI for GTK3 :)

Comment: I've also noticed this [blog entry discussing the use of AppIndicator3](http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2011/08/06/ubuntu-app-indicators-when-using-pygobject/), which you might find interesting.

Comment: Just a note, most of these links are dead.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a stupid simple scaffold application that has a config window, a main window, and an app indicator.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.3

from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator

class MyIndicator:
  def __init__(self, root):
    self.app = root
    self.ind = appindicator.Indicator.new(
                self.app.name,
                "indicator-messages",
                appindicator.IndicatorCategory.APPLICATION_STATUS)
    self.ind.set_status (appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
    self.menu = Gtk.Menu()
    item = Gtk.MenuItem()
    item.set_label("Main Window")
    item.connect("activate", self.app.main_win.cb_show, '')
    self.menu.append(item)

    item = Gtk.MenuItem()
    item.set_label("Configuration")
    item.connect("activate", self.app.conf_win.cb_show, '')
    self.menu.append(item)

    item = Gtk.MenuItem()
    item.set_label("Exit")
    item.connect("activate", self.cb_exit, '')
    self.menu.append(item)

    self.menu.show_all()
    self.ind.set_menu(self.menu)

  def cb_exit(self, w, data):
     Gtk.main_quit()

class MyConfigWin(Gtk.Window):
  def __init__(self, root):
    super().__init__()
    self.app = root
    self.set_title(self.app.name + ' Config Window')

  def cb_show(self, w, data):
    self.show()

class MyMainWin(Gtk.Window):
  def __init__(self, root):
    super().__init__()
    self.app = root
    self.set_title(self.app.name)

  def cb_show(self, w, data):
    self.show()

class MyApp(Gtk.Application):
  def __init__(self, app_name):
    super().__init__()
    self.name = app_name
    self.main_win = MyMainWin(self)
    self.conf_win = MyConfigWin(self)
    self.indicator = MyIndicator(self)

  def run(self):
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = MyApp('Scaffold')
  app.run()
```

Comment: This example still works in 20.04 with small changes: `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, and add `import gi`, `gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')`, `gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')`. I also needed to `sudo apt install gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1`.

Answer (score 9):

Just in case someone might find it useful, I made a minimal app indicator with Python, GIR and GTK3. It reads CPU speeds from /proc/cpuinfo every few seconds and displays them.

See here: https://bitbucket.org/cpbotha/indicator-cpuspeed/src

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example of reading cpu temperature. copy an icon named  temp-icon.png/svg in the script directory

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator
import os

def cb_exit(w, data):
   Gtk.main_quit()

def cb_readcputemp(ind_app):
# get CPU temp
   fileh = open(
      '/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_hwmon/subsystem/devices/coretemp.0/temp1_input',
    'r')
  ind_app.set_label(fileh.read(2), '')
  fileh.close()
  return 1


ind_app = appindicator.Indicator.new_with_path (
  "cputemp-indicator",
   "temp-icon",
   appindicator.IndicatorCategory.APPLICATION_STATUS,
    os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
ind_app.set_status (appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)

# create a menu
menu = Gtk.Menu()
menu_items = Gtk.MenuItem("Exit")
menu.append(menu_items)
menu_items.connect("activate", cb_exit, '')
menu_items.show()
ind_app.set_menu(menu)
GLib.timeout_add(500, cb_readcputemp, ind_app)
Gtk.main()
```