# How to write Appindicators in python?

Tags: application-development, python, indicator

I'm looking to try and develop some simple indicators, for numlock/capslock and brigthness, etc. How would I go about creating indicators in python? Are there any tutorials that walk me through writing my first appindicator (like for apps in quickly)? Any easy solutions for starting like quickly templates?

Comment: Especially appindicators for pyqt5 or pygi and python3 (that will also work outside unity as well).

Answer (score 7):

I think [Writing indicators with Python, GIR and GTK3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108035/writing-indicators-with-python-gir-and-gtk3?rq=1) ,as mentioned by @fossfreedom, covers how create indicators for Unity. (Read that 1st)

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, Quickly 12.08.1 . This is demo for a complete working example build from a Quickly template.

1. OP wants just indicator (not complete GUI app) so let's start with ubuntu-cli Quickly template:

   ```
   quickly create ubuntu-cli indicator-demo
   ```

   It may raise an error message for unreleased bug fix ([bug#1064110](https://bugs.launchpad.net/quickly/+bug/1064110)) in this template:

   ```
   Creating project directory indicator-demo
   Creating bzr repository and committing
   Launching your newly created project!
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   ...
   OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
   ERROR: create command failed
   Aborting
   ```

   Fix permissions

   ```
   cd indicator-demo/
   chmod +x bin/indicator-demo
   ```

   Test

   ```
   $ quickly run
   I'm launched and my args are:
   ```
2. There is a nice **PYGI** example from [Ubuntu Wiki: Application Indicators](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators). It should be easy to integrate it.

   Open for edit:

   ```
   quickly edit
   ```

   - Modify `__init__.py`, add need modules imports:

     ```
     from gi.repository import Gtk
     from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator
     ```
   - In the `main()` function, between:

     ```
     print _("I'm launched and my args are: %s") % (" ".join(args))
     logging.debug(_('end of prog'))
     ```

     add:

     ```
     ind = appindicator.Indicator.new_with_path (
                         _("Indicator demo for Quickly"),
                         "indicator-demo-icon-normal",
                         appindicator.IndicatorCategory.APPLICATION_STATUS,
                         indicator_democonfig.get_data_path())
     ind.set_status (appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
     ind.set_attention_icon ("indicator-demo-icon-attention")

     # create a menu
     menu = Gtk.Menu()

     # create one item 
     menu_items = Gtk.MenuItem(_("Quit"))
     menu.append(menu_items)    
     # this is where you would connect your menu item up with a function:
     menu_items.connect("activate", Gtk.main_quit )    
     # show the item
     menu_items.show()

     ind.set_menu(menu)

     Gtk.main()
     ```
3. Add icons to a newly created data folder:

   ```
   mkdir data
   ```

   I copied some icons from installed packages, just to make the example:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22/indicator-messages.svg data/indicator-demo-icon-normal.svg
   cp /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22/indicator-messages-new.svg data/indicator-demo-icon-attention.svg
   ```
4. Test it:

   ```
   quickly run
   ```
5. Create package and publish it:

   ```
   quickly package
   quickly share --ppa your-ppa
   ```

**Notes:**

1. Well, I didn't update debian package control file, But the dependencies have been auto added to the generated DEB:

   ```
   Package: indicator-demo
   Version: 0.1
   Architecture: all
   Maintainer: UNKNOWN <UNKNOWN>
   Installed-Size: 57
   Depends: python (>= 2.7), python (<< 2.8), python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2), gir1.2-gtk-3.0, gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1
   Section: python
   Priority: extra
   Description: UNKNOWN
    UNKNOWN
   ```

   Also, the previously added icons in data folder were included in the package.
2. I faced a similar case before, [How to add a keyboard modifier state applet to Unity panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402315/how-to-add-a-keyboard-modifier-state-applet-to-unity-panel). The answer contains an example/prototype keyboard indicator using libappindicator (But in the c programming language).

   libappindicator lacks an important feature which make easy to ports other desktops indicators. Icon can be loaded only from path. [See Bug #812067 
   API needed: pixbuf icon setting support](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libappindicator/+bug/812067)

**References:**

- The complete API reference for libappindicator is available as HTML in the `libappindicator-doc` package. Look in `/usr/share/gtk-doc/html/libappindicator/`

  Notice that it supports adding label a beside indicator icon.
- [Ubuntu Wiki: Application Indicators](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators)
- [Ubuntu Wiki: Quickly](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly)

**Related Questions:**

- [Writing indicators with Python, GIR and GTK3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108035/writing-indicators-with-python-gir-and-gtk3?rq=1)
- [How to create Unity indicators?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42211/how-to-create-unity-indicators)

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://conjurecode.com/create-indicator-applet-for-ubuntu-unity-with-python/) link will teach you to create a basic new mail indicator in python+unity, which works with GMail. This will give you a solid grounding in the basic structure of an applet while providing a real-world (albeit simplistic) example that you can easily extend.
It's go through the final script piece by piece.
[This](http://www.eurion.net/python-snippets/snippet/Create%20an%20Application%20Indicator.html) is another python program with comments in code, made using  `Pygtk`

Comment: Note that the first link now points to a non-existent domain (conjurecode.com).