# App-indicator work flow

Tags: 18.04, application-development, indicator

I wanted to learn how app-indicator works in Ubuntu.
I will be really thankful if anyone can help me in 
understanding the workflow of App-indicator.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it changed.  This could be a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing indicators with Python, GIR and GTK3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108035/writing-indicators-with-python-gir-and-gtk3)